# implementing fallback/default-getter in Lua's tables

Tags: lua

Is there a way to implement a mechanism similar to python's `__getitem__`?

for instance, having the following:

```
local t1 = {a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4}
```

if in code, `t1.e` will be called, then I wish to have something else returned rather than `nil`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `setmetatable` and the `__index` metamethod:

```
local t1 = {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}

setmetatable(t1, {
    __index = function(table, key)
        return "something"
    end
})

print(t1.hi) -- prints "something"
```

Note that this will not be called when you do `t.nonexistant = something`. For that, you need the `__newindex` metamethod:

```
local t1 = {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}

setmetatable(t1, {
    __index = function(table, key)
        return "something"
    end,

    __newindex = function(table, key, value)
        rawset(table, tostring(key) .. '_nope', value)
    end
})

print(t1.hi) -- prints "something"
t1.hi = 'asdf'
print(t1.hi) -- prints "something"
print(t1.hi_nope) -- prints "asdf"
```